# How to solve this task using js or ruby. It is necessary to construct a matrix of attainability?

Tags: javascript, matrix

A company has N people. Many of them are friends. Also, interesting
fact is that friends of friends are also friends. You need to find out
how much friends has a particular person in the company.

#### Input data

Function should receive next params:  N - number of people in the
company S - a specific number of person Matrix N lines contain N
numbers consisting of ones and zeros. And the unit standing in the
i-th row and j-th column ensures that people with numbers i and j -
friends, and 0 - expresses uncertainty.

#### Output data

Function should return number of the certain friends of the person
with the S number, remembering transitive friendship.

```
Example1: N = 3  S = 1 Matrix = 0 1 0
               1 0 1
               0 1 0 Result: 2

Example2: N = 5  S = 2 Matrix = 0 0 0 0 0 
               0 0 1 0 0
               0 1 0 0 1
               0 0 0 0 1
               0 0 1 1 0  Result: 3
```

Comment: You should probably attempt your assignment before asking for help with it

Comment: This seems like it would be interesting, however seems poorly articulated, or mabye I am just not understanding the problem. Anyone care to expand on what the problem actually is?